# show progress bar after fade in animation

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, fadein

I have this code to create a fade in animation with an image

push_top_in code create a fade top to bottom animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

JAVA code call the push_top_in animation

```
    ImageView imvLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvLogo); 
    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MisCompras.this, R.animator.push_top_in);
    imvLogo.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

now i want to show a progress bar when animation end and i use this code

```
    myFadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            progressBarCust = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            textViewLoad = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvProgreso);
            Handler hdl = new Handler();
            hdl.postDelayed(new MiSuperHandler(), 5000);       
        }
    });
```

but the setAnimationListener code throws the next exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{miscompras.principal/miscompras.principal.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and i don't know what is wrong

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need the answer, try replacing
   `R.animator.push_top_in`
by 
    `R.anim.push_top_in`